# Refactoring a Google App Engine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In my datastore I had a few hundred entities of kind `PlayerStatistic` that I wanted to rename to `GamePlayRecord`. On the dev server it was easy to do this by writing a small script in the Interactive Console. However there is no Interactive Console once the app has been deployed.

Instead, I copied that script into a file and linked the file in `app.yaml`. I deployed the script, intending to run it once and then delete it. However, I ran into another problem, which is that the script ran for over 30 seconds. The script would always get cut off before it could complete.

My solution ended up being rewriting the script so that it creates and deletes the entities one at a time. That way, even when it timed out, the script could continue where it left off. Since I only have a few hundred entities this took about 5 refreshes.

Is there a better way to run one-time refactoring scripts on Google App Engine? Is there a good way to get around the 30 second limit in order to run these refactoring scripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the task queue.

Tasks can run for more much longer than web requests. You can also split up the work into many tasks, so they will run parallel and finish faster. When you finish the task, you can programmatically insert a new task, so the whole process is automated and you don't need to manually refresh.

Comment: This led me to a Google App Engine article about doing background work using deferred: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html

Answer (score 3):

[appengine-mapreduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) is a good way to do datastore refactoring. It takes care of a lot of the messy details that you would have to grapple with when writing task code by hand.